# Bi-spherical polyhedra

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

[Bicentric polygons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BicentricPolygon.html) have been studied: a polygon all of whose vertices lie on its 
circumcirle, and whose incircle is tangent to every edge:

 [image: BicentricQuads]
I have not been able to find a comparable literature for *bi-spherical polyhedra*:
a polyhedron all of whose vertices lie on a common circumscribed sphere
(so the polyhedron is "inscribed"),
and with an inscribed sphere tangent to every face.
Of course this holds for every Platonic solid:

      [image: DodecaInOut]

      
 <sub>[Left source](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/loci/a-gallery-of-ray-tracing-for-geometers-1); [Right source](http://home.swipnet.se/polyhedra/pcc-dsf.htm)</sub>

Have these bi-spherical polyhedra been characterized? Or at least studied to some extent?

The notion extends to arbitrary dimensions, but I would be happy with some
information for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thanks for pointers!

**Added.** And of course prisms (of the right height) are bi-spherical:

     [image: PrismInCircum]

Comment: Nice question, I am interested too. Just yesterday I was thinking at them, and whether Poncelet's porism theorem can be generalized to spheres and how.

Comment: Wikipedia has an entry on conformal maps and their rarity in higher dimensions (Liouville 1850).  Perhaps this might point you in a useful direction.

Comment: Your list of non-interesting bispherical polyhedra should also include dipyramids (of the right height). The more interesting case of course is when the incenter and circumcenter do not coincide. One example are pyramids of regular polygons.

Comment: Pyramids of regular polygons?

Comment: I.e. with a regular polygon as a base.

Comment: My confusion is that the hexagonal prism I added is regular, and the incenter and circumcenter do coincide...

Comment: Fortunately it does not have to be a regular prism.

Comment: Unless I have miscalculated, for the pyramid the incenter and circumcenter do not coincide (except for a special height).

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I misread "prism" when you wrote "pyramid." Sorry!

Comment: General, non-degenerate simplices should work in any dimension.

Comment: While I'm generally reluctant to make a comment that says "you're asking the wrong question" ... why are you asking for polyhedra with just an insphere and a circumsphere?  It seems natural (to me) to ask for your polyhedron to have a midsphere (i.e. a sphere tangent to every edge) as well.  You then have the nice inductive property that every face (and every vertex figure?) of a "trispherical" polyhedron is a bicentric polygon.

Comment: @MattFayers: Yes, midspheres are beautiful! See, e.g., [Is there a midsphere theorem for 4-polytopes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/478107/237). But I was thinking more along the lines of "Poncelet's porism," as mentioned by Cristi Stoica (although I didn't know it by that name).

Comment: Is it obvious that you should avoid midspheres if you want a 3-dimensional Poncelet's porism?  It feels to me (based on zero examples) that with just an insphere and a circumsphere you have too much freedom in choosing your polyhedron.

Comment: You can also take a prism with a bicentric polygon as its base and also pyramids.

Comment: The affine and projective transformations work in any dimension and are enough to move two nested balls into concentric ones, so the "if one, then infinitely many" part of the Poncelet porism stays valid unless you want a midphere too, in which case you have too many equations to satisfy. I do not know what the analogue of the diagonal crossing could be though.

Comment: @fedja it is true that by affine and projective transformations you can move two balls into concentric ellipsoids, but you cannot guarantee those ellipsoids will be balls, and the same happens in 2D, so this is not immadiately proving Poncelet porism. Note that the picture in Poncelet theorem (at least in 2d) is inherently being acted by an elliptic curve, which is not rational, therefore the theorem is not geometrically trivial.

Comment: @user49822 Looks like you are right :-). One more thing to add to the thread about "commonly believed mathematical statements that are false" (at least, to my personal version of it). Thanks for pointing that out!